# Failure to connect to mySQL DB via PHP (msqli object-oriented issue)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I'm trying to connect from my Heroku app to a mysql db (Xeround) in an object-oriented way:

```
$this->db = new mysqli(
    Credentials::databaseHost(), 
    Credentials::databaseUsername(), 
    Credentials::databasePassword(), 
    Credentials::databaseName());
```

(for clarity--> this line is located within the constrcutor of a central dispatcher I use. The sql connection is injected by this dispatcher if needed)

In my locally running production environment everything is working fine, however once I test it on Heroku the app hangs at the above point. No error msgs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having a similar problem which seems to suggest that Heroku does not support mysqli.

Comment: Marco...sorry...I am not a power user of stackoverflow...didn't see your comment. No, I didn't solve it, but I guess Adam Loso's reply is the answer to our problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if this is still an issue for you guys but no, heroku does not support mysqli.